# Get the sum of previous records based on particular id

Tags: sql-server

How to get the previous values based on particular id 
Sample Table

```
PrimaryIdId  RefId       Amount
1             5           150
2             5           100
3             5           10
```

I need an output as sum of the previous amount as follows

```
Id         Amount      PreviousValue
--------------------------------------
1          150             - 
2          100             150
3          100             250
```

sum of previous records.

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Any more columns so we can give you a good query? Any grouping? How do PrimaryIdId and RefId are interact?

Comment: just 3 records with sample output isn't helping pls do post some more ex!

Comment: in the output, you should also have 10 for Amount for row 3?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select 
     PrimaryIdId ,
     Amount ,
     (select sum(Amount) from Table1 where PrimaryIdId < d.PrimaryIdId )  as PreviousValue
from Table1 d group by PrimaryIdId
```

Comment: Won't work if there are gaps in ID values. For newer MSSQL servers this does happen quite likely even without record deletion..

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2012

```
SELECT
    ID, Amount,
    SUM(Prev) OVER (ORDER BY ID RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
FROM
    (
    SELECT
         PrimaryID AS ID,
         Amount,
         LAG(Amount) OVER (ORDER BY PrimaryID) AS Prev
    FROM
        dbo.Foo
    ) X;
```

If you want the series *per RefId* then

```
SELECT
    ID, Amount, RefId,
    SUM(Prev) OVER (PARTITION BY RefId ORDER BY ID RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
FROM
    (
    SELECT
         PrimaryID AS ID, RefId,
         Amount,
         LAG(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY RefId ORDER BY PrimaryID) AS Prev
    FROM
        dbo.Foo
    ) X;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT S.PrimaryIdId, S.Amount, CA.PreviousValue
FROM SampleTable S
OUTER APPLY 
   (SELECT SUM(Amount) PreviousValue
   FROM SampleTable S2 WHERE S2.RefId = S.RefId AND S2.PrimaryIdId < S.PrimaryIdId) CA
```

Granted, I have a feeling you'll have multiple different sets of RefId, making that result unrecognizable. So you'd likely want something more along the lines of:

```
SELECT S.PrimaryIdId, S.RefId, S.Amount, CA.PreviousValue
FROM SampleTable S
OUTER APPLY 
   (SELECT SUM(Amount) PreviousValue
   FROM SampleTable S2 WHERE S2.RefId = S.RefId AND S2.PrimaryIdId < S.PrimaryIdId) CA
ORDER BY S.RefId, S.PrimaryIdId ASC
```

And if you have SQL Server 2012, you can just use the LAG function.

Comment: And SUM. Not just LAG

Answer (score 0):

```
 ;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT 1   PrimaryId,
                5   RefId,
                150 Amount
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2,
                5,
                100
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3,
                5,
                100),
     cte1
     AS (SELECT *,
                0 AS amt
         FROM   cte a
         WHERE  primaryid = 1
         UNION ALL
         SELECT a.*,
                b.amount + amt
         FROM   cte a
                INNER JOIN cte1 b
                        ON a.primaryid - b.primaryid = 1)
SELECT *
FROM   cte1
```